# Script to convert multiple URLs or files to individual PDFs and save to a specific location

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

I have written a script where I am taking the input of URLs hardcoded and giving their filenames also hardcoded, whereas I want to take the URLs from a saved text file and save their names automatically in a chronological order to a specific folder.

My code (works) :

```
import requests

#input urls and filenames
urls = ['https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1979.nc',
'https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1980.nc',
'https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1981.nc']

fns = [r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1979.nc',
r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1980.nc',
r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1981.nc']

#defining the inputs
inputs= zip(urls,fns)

#define download function
def download_url(args):
    
    url, fn = args[0], args[1]
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed:', e)

#loop through all inputs and run download function
for i in inputs :
    result = download_url(i)
```

Trying to fetch the links from text (error in code):

```
import requests

# getting all URLS from textfile
file = open('C:\\Users\\HBI8\\Downloads\\testing.txt','r')
#for each_url in enumerate(f):
list_of_urls = [(line.strip()).split() for line in file]
file.close()

#input urls and filenames
urls = list_of_urls

fns = [r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1979.nc',
r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1980.nc',
r'C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads\pr_1981.nc']

#defining the inputs
inputs= zip(urls,fns)

#define download function
def download_url(args):
    
    url, fn = args[0], args[1]
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed:', e)

#loop through all inputs and run download fupdftion
for i in inputs :
    result = download_url(i)
```

testing.txt has those 3 links pasted in it on each line.

Error :

```
Failed: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1979.nc']"
Failed: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1980.nc']"
Failed: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1981.nc']"
```

PS :
I am new to python and it would be helpful if someone could advice me on how to loop or go through files from a text file and save them indivually in a chronological order as opposed to hardcoding the names(as I have done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inserted a delimiter as  ',' by using split function.
In order to give automated file name I used the index number of the stored list.

Data saved in following manner in txt file.
FileName | Object ID | Base URL

```
url_file = open('C:\\Users\\HBI8\\Downloads\\testing.txt','r')
fns=[]
list_of_urls = []
for line in url_file:
  stripped_line = line.split(',')
  print(stripped_line)
  list_of_urls.append(stripped_line[2]+stripped_line[1])
  fns.append(stripped_line[0])
url_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `list_of_urls = [(line.strip()).split() for line in file]`, you produce a list of lists. (For each line of the file, you produce the list of urls in this line, and then you make a list of these lists)

What you want is a list of urls.

You could do
`list_of_urls = [url  for line in file for url in (line.strip()).split()]`

Or :

```
list_of_urls = []
for line in file:
   list_of_urls.extend((line.strip()).split())
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest method in this simple case is use the OS command

so go to the work directory `C:\Users\HBI8\Downloads`
invoke cmd (you can simply put that in the address bar)

write/paste your list using >`notepad testing.txt` (if you don't already have it there)

[***Note NC HDF files are NOT.pdf***](https://filext.com/file-extension/NCSA)

```
https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1979.nc
https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1980.nc
https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1981.nc
```

then run

```
for /F %i in (testing.txt) do curl -O %i
```

92 seconds later
[image]